# Asymptotic expression of $(1+bx^a)^n$ as $x\to0$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

Using Taylor expansion, we have $(1+x)^n\to 1+nx$ as $x\to0$. Now if I have a more general expression, say, $(1+bx^a)^n$, then does this expression still have such asymptotic behavior?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you know that $(1 + Y)^n \sim 1 + nY$ as $Y \to 0$, and you call $Y = b x^a$ (for $a > 0$), it remains true that $x \to 0 \implies Y \to 0$.

The full expansion is the binomial expansion, so you really know that
$$ (1 + Y)^n = \sum_{k \geq 0} {n \choose k} Y^k.$$
The first two terms are the terms you give. The remaining terms (finitely many if $n$ is an integer) all have larger powers of $Y$, and as $Y \to 0$ they become very small very quickly.

Comment: If $0<a<1$, I found that the derivative of $x^a$ does not exist at $x=0$.  So I can not apply the Taylor expansion to study the asymptotic behavior. Can you tell me why the Taylor expansion does not work here when $0<a<1$.

Comment: You can still have an asymptotic approximation. It's just not a Taylor series. In general, non-integer power functions do not have a Taylor series around $0$ since they're not infinitely differentiable